# Radom post image/link based on custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, widgets

How would I make a widget to display a random post's image and permalink? I would like it to pull from a specific custom content type and only posts have set the custom field of "featured" to "yes".

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php query_posts( 'cat=36&post_type=athletes&showposts=1&orderby=rand'); ?>
```

changed to :

```
      <?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 36,'category'  => '1','post_type'  => 'athletes', 'orderby' => 'rand');


$lastposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach($lastposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: [Don’t use query_posts()](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts) if you don’t want to overwrite the main query.

Comment: @toscho I changed my code (see edit) but now nothing is displaying. Title of unrelated post.